# Using Array in Case Statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to make the below code work:

```
SELECT [Cell Name]
FROM ******* 

WHERE 

   [Date of maturity year] = (CASE
                             WHEN [Inforce date month] = 12 THEN [Inforce date year] + 1
                             ELSE [Inforce date year]
                             END)                   
And [Date of maturity month] in (7,8,9)
```

This is currently working but I want to make the second where condition dynamic. I have tried to use the Case statement, but it doesn't work.

```
[Date of maturity month] in (CASE
                             WHEN [Inforce date month] = 12 THEN (1,2,3)
                             WHEN [Inforce date month] = 3 THEN (4,5,6)
                             WHEN [Inforce date month] = 6 THEN (7,8,9)
                             ELSE (10,11,12)
                             END)
```

Can someone help me fix this.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: The `x IN ( 1, 2, 3 )` operator in T-SQL is **not** an array-type, it's just syntactic shorthand for `( x = 1 OR x = 2 OR x = 3 )`. T-SQL does not support any kind of array-type (it does have _table-valued_ variables and parameters, but those cannot be used as column types).

Comment: I am using SQL Server management studio

Comment: SSMS is not an RDMBS, it's a frontend tool for SQL Server and Azure SQL. Please become more familiar fundamental database terminology to avoid confusing everyone around you.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Why are you faffing around with comparing date sub-components (which is always error-prone) instead of simply doing a single date range comparison?

Comment: I have those components available as integers in the base table. I am just trying to make he query dynamic to work on any Quarter data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Date of maturity month] - [Inforce date month] % 12 between 1 and 3
```

Comment: This works like charm. I tried the condition on Excel as well with various inputs and it's returning correct output under each test run. Thanks!!

Comment: So powerful, so beautiful an answer. Modulo our way to greatness!